# Problems in persisting polygon object in to postgres

Tags: json, hibernate, polygon

I have to persist a data in to postgres using hibernate 4.  I am having a json string like this which I need to persist in to database:

```
{
    "tags": null,
    "status": "Active",
    "modifiedBy": "user",
    "deleteStartedOn": 0,
    **"boundary": [
        {
            "latitude": -10,
            "longitude": -10
        },
        {
            "latitude": -10,
            "longitude": 10
        },
        {
            "latitude": 10,
            "longitude": 10
        },
        {
            "latitude": 10,
            "longitude": -10
        },
        {
            "latitude": -10,
            "longitude": -10
        }
    ],**
    "createdOn": 1407867173216,
    "modifiedOn": 1407867173216,
    "revision": 1,
    "deleteStartedBy": null,
    "createdBy": "user",
    "description": null,
    "name": "NCR",
    "spId": 1
}
```

If I dont include **boundary** tag in to json ,things are fine. But when I include boundary tag along wit the latitudes and longitude. I get exception:

org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Could not read JSON: Can not deserialize instance of org.postgis.Polygon out of START_ARRAY token

Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of org.postgis.Polygon out of START_ARRAY token
 at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@755ed6df; line: 5, column: 25] (through reference chain: com.main.model.Market["boundary"])

The Json string is valid

I will also show my model too in which boundary is stored 
        @TypeDef(name = "PolygonUserType", typeClass = GeometryUserType.class)
@Type(type="PolygonUserType")
    private Polygon boundary;

```
public Polygon getBoundary() {
    System.out.println("Boundary checked get");
    return boundary;
}

public void setBoundary(Polygon boundary) {
    System.out.println("Boundary checked set");
    this.boundary = boundary;
}
```

Polygon i am using is of org.postgis.polygon

@TypeDef(name = "PolygonUserType", typeClass = GeometryUserType.class) has a custom class GeometryUserType which also is not invoked when I am debugging.